# Haircuts on Saturdays in Hinduism

Tags: scripture, vedas, rituals

Are Haircuts to be avoided on Saturdays as it is considered inauspicious in Hinduism?

If Yes, Are there Hindu mythologies behind this?

https://www.hinduismfacts.org/why-dont-hindus-cut-hair-nails-on-saturdays/

Comment: Namaste and Svagatam to Sanatana Dharma (Hinduism SE). You accepted the below answer too early. There is already a similar question answered. Cutting hair/nails on Saturday or Tuesday decreases your lifespan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any story related to such observance. Just a side note: Hinduism do not prescribe such things. This kind of observances are influenced by local rituals. For example: What to eat and not eat on Ekadashi differ widely in different states in India.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Please see the help centre on how to answer questions and also refer to [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). We insist on citing sources from scriptures and if however an answer such as the above is to be written (where you may not have sources), a comment is recommended instead.

Comment: @Archit - I recommend we start using Sanskrit words when welcoming new comers - How about this template : **Namaste and Svagatam to Sanatana Dharma (Hinduism SE)**

Comment: @ram I don’t mind talking in chat